# MIPS Loading Words and Addresses Explanation

Tags: assembly, mips, memory-address, cpu-registers

I am new to Assembly and working on an assignment pertaining to loading words and addresses in MIPS.  The assignment is to take two words, load them into addresses, then generate the subtraction of the two words into a third word at another address.

As I've progressed through previous programming classes and languages, I like to try to picture what is happening behind the scenes to better understand why calls are made and how the procedures are being performed.  I hope that makes sense, but I always seem to grasp the concepts better when I can conceptualize the topic.  But when it comes to loading words and addresses, I'm still experiencing a disconnect as to why `$lw reg, int(reg)` (where `int` is positive or negative) is used to specify where you want a word to be placed?  I understand that negative goes before the address you specify and positive goes after.  But for some reason I can't understand this topic fully.  I've reviewed other posts here such as: [MIPS Programming Address Storing and Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909734/mips-programming-address-storing-and-loading) and [MIPS Load Word [Address and Content Confusion]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082688/mips-load-word-address-and-content-confusion).  It makes sense to me to a certain degree but I'm still not completely there with understanding when to use it and why.  Why when I load a word, byte, half-word, etc do I need to specify where I want this to be placed in correlation with a specific register and why is this important?  (I know this makes me very ignorant but I'm just learning so please bear with me)

Below is code for the assignment I've been issued.  Now this works, but I do not believe I am using the `la` and `lw` efficiently or correctly.  So for my first question (actually moreso a favor), I'd appreciate it if someone could critique my short program and explain to me how I should be properly using these instructions?

```
#Load address 'first' as a word containing decimal
#Load address 'second' as a word containing decimal
#subtract address second from address first and place it
#into address containing word 'result'

.data
    first: .word 27
    second: .word 8
    result: .word 0

.text
    #load address 'first' word
    la $t0, first
    lw $t1, 0($t0)  #'0' here is probably wrong I'm guessing

    #load address 'second' word
    la $t2, second
    lw $t3, 0($t2)  #'0' here is probably wrong I'm guessing as well

    #load address 'result' word
    la $t4, result

    #subtract contents of 'second' from 'first'
    sub $t4, $t1, $t3

    #move contents of 'result' and print
    move $a0, $t4
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    #terminate program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Now for some reason I can understand when I need to print the contents of an address, using `la` loads the contents for printout of the address I specify.  I get that. I'd say that so far I've used this 98% of the time: `la $a0, xxx`.  This I understand.  But when `lw` is used in conjunction with it and I need to specify an integer in where to place items based on a register, I get completely lost.

My second question pertains to the second portion of this assignment.  Now while I'm not asking for the exact answer, I'm looking for some clarity or examples of what this portion means.

I need to "after result is stored, overwrite both first and second with the result's value.  **Use constant offsets in your store functions to do this.**"  Now I know that constant offsets refers to some factor of (+/-)4 (please correct me if I'm wrong).  But I have no idea what this even remotely means and I expect this to be a direct result of me not fully understanding the `lw` and `la` correlation.

Comment: The `int` in `int(register)` is just an offset added to the register. In your example you can do `la $t0, second` and then `0($t0)` to access `second`, or you could use the fact that you know it's directly after `first` so you could do `la $t0, first` then `4($t0)` to access it. It is more useful for addressing stuff such as arrays or structures where you don't have a label for each element.

Comment: @Jester I'm sorry but I'm still a bit confused.  Let's state that I did `la $t0, first`.  If I wanted to assign a word to that specific address `$t0`, how would that be set?  `lw $t0, 0($t0)`?  and then I can simply do `la $t1, second` followed by `lw $t1, 4($t0)`?  Not exactly sure what you are trying to state.

Comment: `lw` is loading, not storing, you'd want `sw` for that. You don't need to `la $t1, second`, the point is you can address `second` knowing that it's `first+4`.